# Something that I don't understand about python to executable file

Tags: python, py2exe

I mean while you transfer python to executable, if the following python script has some modules imported, how will any other device will run the executable file if it doesn't have python installed without the modules?

Comment: Because the modules are packaged up inside the exe.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated executable is essentially a packaged combination of the python interpreter and the compiled (.pyc) files, including any imported packages that might be necessary.